# Issues while uploading an image to firebase storage with Antd upload action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, antd

I'm using antd [picture-wall/card](https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-picture-card) example to upload images to my firebase storage with this [reference code](https://codesandbox.io/s/ym52x4q1p1) and the only place I'm changing is `action` property on `<Upload>` component.

On the `action` property, I'm using a function that uploads the images to firebase storage instead of a link *both are accepted as seen in docs*.

My action function looks like this;

```js
export async function uploadImage(file) {
    const storage = firebase.storage()
    const metadata = {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg'
    }
    const storageRef = await storage.ref()
    const imageName = generateHashName() //a unique name for the image
    const imgFile = storageRef.child(`Vince Wear/${imageName}.png`)
    return imgFile.put(file, metadata)
}
```

**Issue comes,** The image uploads to firebase successfully, but I keep getting antd response handling errors and possibly not sure what `action` function should return, even though, is written in the docs that it should return a promise.

Error message:

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

Errors also appear as a red border on the uploaded image thumbnail.

**Requested help,** What should my action function return to get rid of errors. I can parse my firebase response and return the necessary details to antd upload action.

**Using**

```
    "antd": "^3.9.2",
    "firebase": "^5.8.5",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
```

Comment: try to create a new object of the imgFile type instead of injecting it from the dom oO

Comment: @jonathanHeindl Why, I don't believe that is the issue since the image successfully uploads to Firebase.

Comment: oh sry I missed that :( have you already tried other standard return values ? like true or void ?

Comment: btw I checked the source code type defeinition (which is not very helpful :/ ) `action?: string | ((file: UploadFile) => PromiseLike<any>);`

Comment: ok antd just passes the upload to rc-upload in version 2.6.0 (!! if the dependency resolver asumed it could upgrade to the most recent version action functions are handled the same ) but in version 2.6.0 thers 2 options : either it gets handled as an ajax uploader which asumes an url to be returned (since it directly puts the return value in a request as url ) or the iframeuplaoder which just adds it as a form Attribute oO , I suggest trying an url like www.google.de for testing even though Im not sure which http MEthod it expects at this moment

Comment: ok pretty sure its a post request

Comment: (if you already read my previous comment in thge most recent version action functions are still supported [I accidentally checked on a fork where someone changed it])

Comment: oh if its the iframeRequest it gets added as the action attribute of a form so I guess it should be something like void or oO idk well somethiong that doesnt hurt to put as action in a form (no empty string)

Comment: sources actual uplaod scripts (see ajaxUploader and IframeUploader)  https://github.com/react-component/upload/tree/7686339cd81566e85186198582dfd9b8370eb4da/src
dependency of antd : ` "rc-upload": "~2.6.0",`  nad herer the antd upLoad script that passes everything on line 304 to the rc-upload https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/upload/Upload.tsx

Comment: oO this is probably enough to formulate it as an answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `customRequest` prop to fix this issue. Have a look

```js
class CustomUpload extends Component {
  state = { loading: false, imageUrl: '' };
  
  handleChange = (info) => {
    if (info.file.status === 'uploading') {
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      return;
    }
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
      getBase64(info.file.originFileObj, imageUrl => this.setState({
        imageUrl,
        loading: false
      }));
    }
  };

  beforeUpload = (file) => {
    const isImage = file.type.indexOf('image/') === 0;
    if (!isImage) {
      AntMessage.error('You can only upload image file!');
    }
    
    // You can remove this validation if you want
    const isLt5M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 5;
    if (!isLt5M) {
      AntMessage.error('Image must smaller than 5MB!');
    }
    return isImage && isLt5M;
  };

  customUpload = ({ onError, onSuccess, file }) => {
    const storage = firebase.storage();
    const metadata = {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg'
    }
    const storageRef = await storage.ref();
    const imageName = generateHashName(); //a unique name for the image
    const imgFile = storageRef.child(`Vince Wear/${imageName}.png`);
    try {
      const image = await imgFile.put(file, metadata);
      onSuccess(null, image);
    } catch(e) {
      onError(e);
    }
  };
  
  render () {
    const { loading, imageUrl } = this.state;
    const uploadButton = (
    <div>
      <Icon type={loading ? 'loading' : 'plus'} />
      <div className="ant-upload-text">Upload</div>
    </div>
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <Upload
          name="avatar"
          listType="picture-card"
          className="avatar-uploader"
          beforeUpload={this.beforeUpload}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          customRequest={this.customUpload}
        >
          {imageUrl ? <img src={imageUrl} alt="avatar" /> : uploadButton}
        </Upload>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just leaving this here incase anyone wanted to track the progress of the file aswell

```
 const customUpload = async ({ onError, onSuccess, file, onProgress }) => {
    let fileId = uuidv4()
    const fileRef = stg.ref('demo').child(fileId)
    try {
      const image = fileRef.put(file, { customMetadata: { uploadedBy: myName, fileName: file.name } })

      image.on(
        'state_changed',
        (snap) => onProgress({ percent: (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100 }),
        (err) => onError(err),
        () => onSuccess(null, image.metadata_)
      )
    } catch (e) {
      onError(e)
    }
  }
```