# How to use CustomRequest with antd upload function to upload images to firebase?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, antd

I'm trying to use the antd upload component and [pictures wall](https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-picture-card) example to upload images to my firebase storage.

Initially i tried using the action property [as out lined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472832/issues-while-uploading-an-image-to-firebase-storage-with-antd-upload-action) with the same results. I then tried using the customRequest form as outlined in the solution to that question. After struggling all day, I just can't seem to get it to work. Clearly I don't understand whats going on well enough.

My various change functions..

```
  handleCancel = () => this.setState({ previewVisible: false });

  handlePreview = async file => {
    if (!file.url && !file.preview) {
      file.preview = await getBase64(file.originFileObj);
    }

    this.setState({
      previewImage: file.url || file.preview,
      previewVisible: true,
    });
  };

  handleChange = (info) => {
    console.log('handleChange',info);
    if (info.file.status === 'uploading') {
      console.log('setting loading to true');
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      return;
    }
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
      console.log('setting loading to false');
      getBase64(info.file.originFileObj, imageUrl => this.setState({
        imageUrl,
        loading: false
      }));
    }
  };
```

my customupload function..

```
  customUpload = async ({ onError, onSuccess, file }) => {
    console.log("customUpload called");
    console.log(file);
    const storage = firebase.storage();
    const metadata = {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg'
    };
    const storageRef = await storage.ref();
    // const imageName = generateHashName() //a unique name for the image
    const imgFile = storageRef.child(`Property Photos/${file}.png`);
    try {
      const image = await imgFile.put(file, metadata);
      onSuccess(null, image);
    }
    catch(e) {
       onError(e);
    };
  };
```

my render JSX..

```
<Form.Item label="Photos">
  <div className="clearfix">
    <Upload
      listType="picture-card"
      fileList={fileList}
      multiple={true}
      accept="image"
      onPreview={this.handlePreview}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      customRequest={this.customUpload}
    >
      {this.imageUrl ? <img src={this.imageUrl} alt="avatar" /> : uploadButton}
    </Upload>
    <Modal visible={previewVisible} footer={null} onCancel={this.handleCancel}>
      <img alt="example" style={{ width: '100%' }} src={previewImage} />
    </Modal>
  </div>
</Form.Item>
```

Funny enough it runs and sort of works, but seems to have three issues..

1. When I upload an image(s) the card/box(s) shows "Upload" with the animated spinning wheel forever. It never completes and shows the image thumbnail.
2. When selecting mulitple images, only the first one seems to end up on firebase. Never more..
3. When selecting the image(s) to upload and clicking OK, there is a long pause (5 seconds?) like the application hangs before i can click anything again. not sure why that is.

It feels like i just don't understand how to use this customRequest property..

Answer (score 2):

In general, what has to be done is: connect the "onProgress", "onSuccess" and "onError" callback functions of 'antd Upload' to the corresponding event observers of cloudStorage upload function.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress

So, the customRequest function can be as:

```js
let customRequest = ({
    file,
    onSuccess,
    onError,
    onProgress,
}) => {
    var uploadTask = storageRef.child(`images/${file.name}`).put(file);

    // Register three observers:
    // 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
    // 2. Error observer, called on failure
    // 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
    uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        function (snapshot) {
            // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
            // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
            var progress =
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");

            // CONNECT ON PROGRESS
            onProgress(progress)

            switch (snapshot.state) {
                case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                    console.log("Upload is paused");
                    break;
                case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                    console.log("Upload is running");
                    break;
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads

            // CONNECT ON ERROR
            onError(error)
        },
        function () {
            // Handle successful uploads on complete
            // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref
                .getDownloadURL()
                .then(function (downloadURL) {
                    console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
 
                    // CONNECT ON SUCCESS
                    onSuccess(downloadURL)  // Pass any parameter you would like
                });
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: It looks like whether i pick one or multiple files they do upload to firebase so thats good. But antd doesn't show the thumbnails and i notice my handlechange function only gets called initially when info.file.status is 'uploading'. It never gets called a second time when info.file.status is 'done. It seems like antd isn't picking up on the fact that the files were successfully uploaded even though onsuccess was called as is evident by my seeing the console.log of the "file availalble at" along with the downloadURL.

Comment: Am I supposed to do something more here such that antd knows the files were uploaded, handlechange gets called, and i see the thumbnails of hte uploaded images? seems like i'm still missing something.